# Memory violation accessing an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

i'm on the pointer learning curve and could really use some direction / assistance. I want to have an array of structs, with each struct being a 'cell' that keeps track of various things. Everything seems to work fine, no compiling errors or anything and i'm using the array to generate a map. The issue comes when i try and access the array at various points. Sometimes i get a memory access violation, sometimes i don't - which mean's i'm getting lucky. I'm very new to C so any help is appreciated - or pointing in the right direction. I really want to understand why and where I've gone wrong, and i get the feeling it's my pointers and memory - am i passing things correctly? Thank in advance.

```
#define ysize 20
#define xsize 80

typedef struct cells {
    int type;
    bool visited;
    bool passable;
    int item;
} cells;

int getCell(int x, int y, struct cells **map)
{
    return map[x + xsize * y]->type;
}
void setCell(int x, int y, int celltype, struct cells **map)
{
    map[x + xsize * y]->type = celltype;
}
struct cells **makeMap()
{
    struct cells **map = malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(struct cells *));
    for (int i = 0; i != xsize * ysize; i++) {
        map[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct cells ));
        map[i]->type = 0;
        map[i]->item = 0;
        map[i]->passable = true;
        map[i]->visited = false;
    }
    return map;
}


void main()
{
    struct cells ** map = makeMap();
    //getRand generates a random number between the min and max supplied.
    int x = getRand(0, xsize);
    int y = getRand(0, ysize);

    if (getCell(x, y, map) == tileCorridor || getCell(x, y, map) == tileDirtFloor){
        //map[x + xsize * y]->item = 3;
        //printf("%d", getCell(x, y, map));
    }
    // this is where the code is failing. 
    //sometimes it works, others it generates a memory error

    destroyMap(map);
}
```

Comment: what are the values of x,y : post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: <s>`void main()`</s> `int main()`

Comment: You seem to be confused as to whether you want a 1-dimensional map, where you compute the index of a `struct` from its coordinates, or a 2-D map, where you have a 1-D array of pointers to other 1-D arrays of `struct`. In the first case, you don't need 2 stars (unless you want to set the pointer via a function argument instead of the function return value).

Comment: Why do you need an array of pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing the index calculation into a one dimensional you don't need to a two dimensional array. Here is a fuctional version of your code. I've improvised `getRand` and removed `destroyMap` both of which were still missing and added the includes.

Since the posted code mainly worked, maybe the error was elsewhere. Possibly your indices were out of bounds.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ysize 20
#define xsize 80

typedef struct cells {
    int type;
    bool visited;
    bool passable;
    int item;
} cells;

int getCell(int x, int y, struct cells *map)
{
    return map[x + xsize * y].type;
}
void setCell(int x, int y, int celltype, struct cells*map)
{
    map[x + xsize * y].type = celltype;
}
struct cells *makeMap()
{
    struct cells *map = (cells*) malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(struct cells));
    for (int i = 0; i != xsize * ysize; i++) {
        map[i].type = i;
        map[i].item = 0;
        map[i].passable = true;
        map[i].visited = false;
    }
    return map;
}


int main()
{
    struct cells * map = makeMap();
    //getRand generates a random number between the min and max supplied.

    for( int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        int x = rand() % xsize;
        int y = rand() % ysize;

        int tileCorridor = 21;
        int tileDirtFloor = 143;


        if (getCell(x, y, map) == tileCorridor || getCell(x, y, map) == tileDirtFloor){
            //map[x + xsize * y]->item = 3;
            printf("%d at [%d, %d] \n", getCell(x, y, map), x , y);
        }
        // this is where the code is failing. 
        //sometimes it works, others it generates a memory error
    }
    free(map);
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/398e20ca0c2cfd77)

Comment: I can see what I'd done wrong now, thanks very much for that. I seem to have gotten confused between my array types. Apologies for not including all my code - i'll remember to make it compile-able next time i post. I've been learning C using the web site 'learn C the hard way' - think i need to do some more digging into array's and pointers to get them clear in my head. This works perfectly. Thank you so much.